# How to input video (frames) into a GLSL shader

Tags: opencv, opengl, glsl, video-processing

I'm trying to do video processing using GLSL. I'm using OpenCV to open a video file up and take each frame as a single image an then I want to use each frame in a GLSL shader

What is the best/ideal/smart solution to using video with GLSL?

## Reading From Video

```
VideoCapture cap("movie.MOV");
Mat image;
bool success = cap.read(image);
if(!success)
{
    printf("Could not grab a frame\n\7");
    exit(0);
}
```

## Image to Texture

```
 GLuint tex;
 glGenTextures(1, tex);
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.cols, image.rows, 0,
                GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);

 glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Texture"), 0);
```

### What needs to be in my render while loop?

Do I need to recompile/reattach/relink my shader every time? Or Once my shader is created and compiled and I use `glUseProgram(shaderProgram)` can I keep sending it new textures?

The current loop I've been using to render a texture to the screen is as follows. How Could I adapt this to work with video? Where would I need to make my calls to update the texture being used in the shader?

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0,0,512,512);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows, 0, 0, image.cols, image.rows, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);


    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: IplImages are a blast from the past. use cv::Mat and cv::VideoCapture

Comment: Ok, I updated it to use cv::Mat.

Comment: downvote revoked. please do the same to the capture. your post will stay *forever* on SO

Comment: @karlphillip I just started the webpage, its a work in progress, thanks for the input though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's clarify a few things that needs to happen **before the loop**:

- Set the pixel storage mode with `glPixelStorei()`;
- Generate only one texture with `glGenTextures()`, because at every iteration of the loop its content will be replaced with new data;
- Compile the shader with `glCompileShader()`, use `glCreateShader()` to create a shader object, invoke `glCreateProgram()`to create a program, call `glAttachShader()` to attach the shader object to the new program, and finally `glLinkProgram()` to make everything ready to go.

That said, **every iteration of the loop** must:

- Clear the color and depth buffer;
- Load the *modelview* matrix with the identity matrix;
- Specify the location where the drawing is going to happen `glTranslatef()`;
- Retrieve a new frame from the video;
- **Enable** the appropriate texture target, **bind** it and then transfer the frame to the GPU with `glTexImage2D()`;
- Invoke `glUseProgram()` to activate your GLSL shader;
- Draw a 2D face using `GL_QUADS` or whatever;
- Disable the program with `glUseProgram(0)`;
- Disable the texture target with `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_YOUR_TEXTURE_TARGET)`;

This is more or less what needs to be done.

**By the way**: [**here's my OpenCV/OpenGL/Qt application**](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvQTcameraGL) that retrieves frames from the camera and displays it in a window. No shaders, though.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for outlining the steps it is very easy to follow

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a framebuffer to send textures to the shader. Once you've got texture 0 selected as the active texture and 0 set as the value of the uniform sampler2D in your shader, every time you call `glBindTexture()`, it will set the sampler2D to whichever texture you've specified in the function parameter. So no, you don't need to relink or recompile your shader each time you want to change texture.

Comment: Oh the reason I had the frame buffer object in my example code. Is because I'm actually processing two streams of video together. and I need to get two frame out of my shader. So I was using `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`

Comment: You could always bind two textures simultaneously, one using texture slot 0 and one using texture slot 1, and then have two `sampler2D`s in your shader.